# Laser Cavity Power vs. Output Power

Tags: laser-cavity

I think I read recently that the power inside a semiconductor’s resonator cavity can reach the megawatt level, due to the buildup of standing waves in the gain material, even though the output power may be in the milliwatts. Unfortunately, I cannot find the article I think I glimpsed, so I come to the members of this forum. Is that true?

I understand the precise answer has to do with Q, finesse, refractive index, mirror reflectivity, equilibrium, and probably a host of other factors, but the product specifications of run-of-the-mill lasers don’t list them. (Perhaps there are industry standards for them so one can assume that, for a given output power the cavity power should be about 10^x times greater.)

My final questions, then: A) How can one measure resonator cavity power? It seems any attempt at measurement would interfere with lasing and produce a faulty measurement. B) Can that megawatt level of cavity power be true for mass-produced laser diodes? C) Whether yes or no, is it possible to estimate the cavity power in such a laser? For example, how much cavity power is required to generate a 1W CW beam of an arbitrary wavelength?

Comment: You may be mistaking peak power with steady state average power.

Comment: @KFGauss but even a megawatt peak power lasting only 1nsec is difficult to believe, I mean, what crystal can take that high field intensity?

Comment: @KFGauss, my understanding is that peak power applies to the output over a nano- or even femtosecond duration. I don't think the article I glimpsed was talking about short pulse lasers, but CW lasers. Would the very large internal power to output power ratio make sense in that scenario?

Comment: @Hyportnex, where should I go to learn more about the field intensity you're concerned about? I expected respondents to be more concerned about dissipation of thermal energy.

Comment: @hyportnex these peak powers come up in femtosecond-ish pulses usually, not nanoseconds (a $10^6$ difference!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ratio of power in the cavity to power dissipated per round trip is called Q. See [Q Factor](https://www.rp-photonics.com/q_factor.html). If other losses are low, dissipation is the power in the beam. The ratio you quote corresponds to $Q = 10^9$.

A Q this high is possible, but not common. It takes a dielectric [supermirror](https://www.rp-photonics.com/supermirrors.html) to achieve.

For a high Q, the cavity is sharply tuned to a single frequency, $\nu_0$. Power of nearby frequencies is much less. The power spectrum is a sharp peak centered on $\nu_0$. A way to measure Q is from $\delta \nu$, the full width of the peak at half max power. $Q = \nu_0/\delta \nu$. So you can just measure frequency vs power.

Here is a [data sheet](https://www.toptica-eagleyard.com/wp-content/uploads/data_sheets/EYP-BAL-0670-00001-1510-SOT23-0010.pdf) for a 1.8 W laser diode I selected at random. You can see from the graph the full width is roughly $1/2$ nm around a peak at $672$ nm. So Q is maybe $1300$.

Comment: but the question is about power, not power to dissipation ratio. I cannot imagine a crystal being able to take that high field intensity even if only for a nanosec.

Comment: @mmesser314, Thank you for your response. I'm going to need some time to fully consider what you and Hyportnex are saying above. Please expect clarification questions in the near future.

Comment: @mmesser314, I think you have answered my question exactly. Thank you for taking the time to apply some mental energy to it.